# How to protect potentiometer in adjustable soldering iron?

Tags: potentiometer, triac, phase, dimmer, soldering-iron-station

I have an adjustable soldering iron and noticed that recently at some position of the adjustment potentiometer (`R3` in the schematic below, this is the potentiometer that is mounted at the panel and is used to set the power), the iron wouldn't heat up at all. After taking it apart and inspecting the potentiometer, it looked like the tracks were damaged especially towards one end. (The end towards max power/least resistance.) It seemed to me that the potentiometer would just have to conduct more current than it was designed for.

To analyze the situation I drew the schematic from the PCB which looks as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDUPr6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as I understand, it is pretty much identical [this circuit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_control_schematics.svg), which is a forward phase control dimmer.

So far I thought about replacing the `R3` (the power adjustment pot) with an identical one, but I fear it will suffer the same fate as the original one, and I have the imporession that this circuit was not built to last. So I wondered:

**Q:** Would it be possible to somehow "protect" `R3`, especially in the low resistance range?

I could just add an greater resistor in series with `R1`, but that would lower the maximal power output which is not ideal. (The iron has to be used close to the max setting.)

Comment: It seems strange that both pots are identical and in parallel. I suspect that you have an error in your diagram.

Comment: @Transistor They are indeed in parallel - I assume the trim pot sets the minimum power, but it was set to close to 500k.

Comment: OK. That could be replaced by a 390k fixed resistor and a 100k pot then. You'd have 20% power dissipation in that pot. How much of the range of the other pot is used?

Comment: Now I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing, so just to clarify: `R3` is the potentiometer at the panel that I use to adjust the temperature, and this is the one that was damaged. The trimpot is fine as it is set to close to 500k. Are you suggesting replacing `R3` wtih a fixed resistor + 100k?

Comment: If the trim pot is OK then leave it alone. For R3 - you could replace it with a fixed resistor (which would set the maximum temperature) and a pot of lower value than originally supplied. You'd have finer control. A better quality pot might also help.

Comment: Then triac opened, all control circuit is short, triac drop voltage around 1V. So on max wattage only short impulse going through control circuit.  Resistor could be damaged by overheating, the average current is should be taken for calculation. You conclusion may be wrong, it is just defected resistor.

Comment: You could put a resistor in series with the pot to give it a minimum resistance.  In fact I'd say it's your R1 which is too small for the job. You should evaluate the reactance of C1 but assuming it's zero (which it isn't!) at 230V you would have more than 200mA on the wiper at the top end